# An entire room lost power

Tags: receptacle

So last night I was plugging a power strip into a wall socket in my son's room. As soon as the prongs touched the socket the whole room went dead. Being a bedroom is should not be affected by GFCI outlets but I checked them all anyway. I also checked the breaker box even though the other room that is on that circuit is still live and with power.

In the room in question I have 4 outlets and one light switch. All are dead. I do not have a colt meter so I commenced to changing the outlet that I originally tried to plug something in.  While I had the outlet out I noticed it was at the end of the line with only having one hot and one white. I went ahead with the replacement because my son wanted an outlet with built in USB power spots.

So now I am literally going outlet by outlet replacing them and turning the power back on and testing it. Nothing seems to be working. I have replaced 3 of the 4 outlets and am still getting no power to the room.

Before I replace them I am checking the brass tabs on the sides and also changing them all from backstab to screws. Nothing has made a difference.  Am I missing something or am I stuck doing this over and over until I find the broken one?

Comment: Is there an arc fault (AFCI) *receptacle* in the line? Maybe one for one bedroom and one for the other. The plug strip may have given a transient that tripped the AFCI receptacle.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are one of your breakers is in fact tripped, but the handle does not appear to be tripped.  Try turning them all off, then back on one by one.  Knowing which breaker really goes where is handy -- a breaker finder tool may be available at a local [tool lending library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_library).

If it's really the wire between outlets, then look in the "live" room.  One of those outlets will have a feed wire, another will have the daisy chain wire to your "dead" room.  Perhaps that backstab has failed.

A voltmeter is a good investment.